# String to numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to print this `F(Rr)` but if use `:^15.10f` in the code this give me a error

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

How do I print this?

```
from numpy import exp

Ri = 15
Rr = 31/2
Rs = 16
i = 0
Er = 0
Rra = 0

def F(n):
    return 745 * 1 - exp(-x / 10) - 49 * x

# Funcion para calcular el error relativo
def error (Rra, Rrn):
    Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
    return Erel

print ('{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format('# iter', 'Ri', 'Rs', 'Rr', 'F(Ri)', 'Erel(%)'))

while (i < 10):
    Er = error(Rra,Rr)
    Rra = Rr #Rra sera el Rr anterior para determinar el error relativo
    if F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es' ,Rr)

    Rr = (Ri + Rs) / 2
    i = i + 1

    # Condicional para el primer error relativo
    if i == 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{}'.format(i - 1, Ri, Rs, Rr, F(Rr)))
    elif i > 1:
             print ('{:^15}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{:^15.6f}{}{:^15.10f}'.format(i - 1, Ri, Rs, Rr, F(Rr), Er))
```

Comment: Which line gives you that error?  I don't see a problem here.  The `{:^15,6f}` format won't work if the parameter is an array, but your example doesn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change "def F(n):" to "def F(x):" or can the calculation within to use n instead of x.
2. Move the print() function to the end.
3. Replace the strings in .format() with variable names.

Revised code:

```
from numpy import exp

Ri = 15
Rr = 31 / 2
Rs = 16
i = 0
Er = 0
Rra = 0


def F(n):
    return 745 * 1 - exp(-n / 10) - 49 * n

# Funcion para calcular el error relativo
def error(Rra, Rrn):
    Erel = abs((Rrn - Rra) / Rrn) * 100
    return Erel


while (i < 10):
    Er = error(Rra, Rr)
    Rra = Rr

    # Rra sera el Rr anterior para determinar el error relativo`
    if F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() < 0:
        Rs = Rr
    elif F(Ri).all() * F(Rr).all() > 0:
        Ri = Rr
    elif F(Rr) == 0:
        print('La raiz es', Rr)

    Rr = (Ri + Rs) / 2
    i = i + 1

print('{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}'.format(i, Ri, Rs, Rr, F(Ri), Er))
```